# How to handle spaces in external table location path

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create an external table based on files stored in Azure Data Lake storage.

Everything works as expected for all paths except the ones containing spaces in them.

```
create or replace external table CG 
with location = '@stg/bc4ps/dbo/test$G_L Entry/'
file_format = ( FORMAT_NAME = csv);
```

Above code returns error message "invalid URL: '@stg/bc4ps/dbo/test$G_L Entry/'".

Single quotes don't seem to be escaping the spaces in external table location path.

Documentation page does not mention anything regarding spaces in paths either.

How do I get the paths with spaces working?

Comment: does inserting `%20` instead of the space work? Given spaces are not valid in URL encoding and %20 is the standard representation.

Comment: I am having the same issue and just tried the `%20` approach but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for what ever reason CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE location is not accepting spaces when using Azure Data Lake Gen 2. The only way I got this working was with the help of a regex pattern.

I pointed the location to be the root folder and then used pattern to filter the right files.

```
create external table CG
  with location = @stg/bc4ps/dbo/
  file_format = ( FORMAT_NAME = csv)
  pattern = '.*G_L Entry.*.csv$';
```

Above regex does this:

```
.* - multiple characters
G_L Entry - my search string
.* - multiple characters
.csv - only takes csv extension
$ - indicates end of string
```

At this point in time I have only a limited dev environment with very little data to test with and am not able to check in what way regex pattern affects performance (if it does at all).

Answer (score 1):

so yes,  drop the single quotes and replace the space with `%20`

```
create stage stg  URL ='s3://buck_name/path_mc_pathy_path_path/';

create file format csv;

create external table CG
  with location = @stg/bc4ps/dbo/test$G_L%20Entry/
  file_format = ( FORMAT_NAME = csv);
```

Comment: Interesting that this solution is accepted by the CREATE table command. Checked the newly created table settings and the URL looks exactly like the one in Azure Storage Explorer properties. 

However the resulting table is empty: select * form cg -> Query produced no results.

Comment: Does azure have notes on how to encode spaces that are different from %20 ?

Comment: Is it \u0020 that should be used?

Comment: \u0020 does not work either.  Not able to find anything more about spaces in azure URLs than just standard %20 encoding.
What is even stranger is that the file names contain spaces as well. But Snowflake has no problems finding those. It is just spaces within the location path.

Comment: Sigh. Fall back to the classic advise, if it doesn’t work, don't do that (spaces). Double sigh. But it makes some sense. That path is pass as a filter where-as the list of files will be handled via request body/data not in a url.